# Excel VLOOKUP function giving the incorrect value. Can somebody identify mistake?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have been using the `VLOOKUP` function a lot in Microsoft Excel but these last two days have been rough.  I have been trying to "match" the state population with the state name.  I was able to use the `VLOOKUP` function to match the State Abbreviation to the State name but can't do what I mentioned above.

I know I should use `VLOOKUP` for values in column B with the table in columns N and O

[image: screenshot]

I have tried modifying the function and I have only been able to get it to spit out Wyoming and Texas populations. Also when I type FALSE it gives me an `N/A` error.  If anyone knows how to fix this I would be grateful

Comment: Column N must be sorted ascending.

Comment: @Tyson I put it in ascending order.  Then I used =VLOOKUP(B2,$N$2:$O$53,2) I was trying to get it to spit out Alaska's population but it spits out Wyoming's.

Comment: @piza25 I'm not sure what you mean, Column N is definitely not sorted in the screenshot.

Comment: @Tyson I sorted it after I read your first comment.  That was the only thing I changed.  I then typed out =VLOOKUP(B2,$N$2:$O$53,2) in cell D2.  It gave me Wyoming's population instead of Alaska's.

Comment: @piza25 Please edit your question to show the latest screenshot and include anything else that might have changes since you first posted the question.

Comment: @Blackwood I posted the latest imgur and deleted the old screenshot.

Comment: The value being spit out is 579315.  This is the population of Wyoming. It should give me Alaska's population value instead.  (Can't see in the screenshot) but Wyoming is the last value in Column N and 579315 is the last value in column O.

Comment: I noticed every cell in col B has a green triangle in the upper left corner.  That indicates an error condition (see https://www.lifewire.com/excels-red-and-green-triangle-indicators-3124031).  I suspect that there is a problem with what is actually contained in those cells that's causing the col B value to not match the entry in the lookup table (in which case it returns the last value in the table).

Answer (score 0):

**I've used *Absolute Cell reference* with *False* option and with this little correction this formula is working properly.**

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(A42,$E$42:$F$46,2,FALSE)
```

**Note,**

- Purposely I've created RANDOM list to 
  justify the efficiency of the formula.
- Adjust the cell references in formula 
  as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using an absolute reference for the lookup range is required for copying a formula down the column. The problem is the state name column (B) begins at position one in the cells while in the lookup range column (N), the state names are preceded by a space. E.g, `North Dakota`, both in column B and in its source, column J (where column B's own lookup finds it).

You can clean the state population list of the leading spaces using `TRIM()`.

A complete alternative, given the certainty of the data sets, would be to just note that each line is the same state and simply read the cells directly.

If using `VLOOKUP()` after cleaning the data, one should absolutely use "FALSE" as the 4th parameter on data sets like these and naturally use "structured references" (the lookup ranges are in Tables after all), or absolute addressing in order to copy down.

Nowadays (2022), probably the lookup range is taken care of (definitely with this exact formula) by `SPILL`-ing, but in the day, it would have been needed.

The key is asking why the column B cells are marked; reading the "error" content then wondering what could cause that.